# Tensor and Gauss divergence theorem

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, tensors

I am trying to see whether, in spherical coordinates,
$$\int \left( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{T} \right) \cdot \boldsymbol{e}_z dV$$ where $T$ is a 2D symmetric tensor, $r$ is a vector and $\boldsymbol{e}_z = (\cos \theta, -\sin \theta, 0)$ ,  can be put under the form $$\int \left(  \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot a \boldsymbol{v} \right) dV$$ where $v$ would be a vector, and $a$ a scalar, or something else such that I could use Gauss divergence theorem.
If I am not mistaken, $$\int \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{T}dV = \int \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot  \left(\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T} \right) dV$$ but I don't know what to do with this $\boldsymbol{e}_z$ vector, as it is a function of $\theta$.
Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

edit: Basically, I take the cross product of $\boldsymbol{r}$ with the momentum equation

$$ \frac{\partial \rho \boldsymbol{u}}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{T} = 0$$

multiply by $\boldsymbol{e}_z$ and integrate it over the (spherical) domain's volume,

$$    \int \frac{\partial \rho r \sin \theta u_\varphi}{\partial t} dV  =  - \int  \boldsymbol{e}_z \cdot \left(\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{T} \right) dV \ .$$

Hence, the last term is the viscous torque in the $z$-direction. What I currently have is the following:

$$\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{T} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot  \left( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T} \right)$$

Because $T$ is symmetric. Also,    $$\boldsymbol{e}_z \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T} \right) = \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot  \left[\left( \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T}  \right) \boldsymbol{e}_z \right]$$

Because $ {\rm grad} \boldsymbol{e}_z = 0 $. The last integral thus reads

$$- \int_{\partial R} \left[\left(   \boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T} \right) \cdot \boldsymbol{e}_z \right] \cdot \boldsymbol{n}_\perp dS $$

If $\boldsymbol{n}_\perp = \boldsymbol{e}_r$, then it becomes
$$- \int_{\partial R} R \sin \theta T_{r \varphi} dS$$

But I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: You're going to need to be more precise about the definition of $\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{T}$ for tensor $\mathbf{T}$. Depending on your convention, that might be $-\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{r})$.

Comment: Thanks. See edit for more details.

Comment: It's not clear what $\boldsymbol r\times\mathbf T$ actually is. You will need to come up with some sort of definition using the Levi-Civita tensor.

Comment: Also the "momentum equation".... I assume you're looking at Navier-Stokes? Fluids are my specialty, so what is the broader context of your question? Why are you taking the cross product of the momentum equation?

Comment: Hi, I skipped all the terms that are not related to the specific problem, I only kept the viscous term. $T$ is the viscous stress tensor, i.e. $T_{ij} =-\rho \nu \left( \partial_i u_j + \partial_j u_i - \frac{2}{3} (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{u}) \delta_{ij} \right)$. Basically, the integral on the   left hand side is the time evolution of is the $z$-component of the angular momentum, and the integral on the right is the viscous torque (I have not shown the advective and gravitational torques).

Comment: I guess that $\left(\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{T}\right)_{il}$ would be written $\epsilon_{ijk} x_j T_{kl}$ using Levi-Civita tensor, with $\boldsymbol{r} = x_k \boldsymbol{e}_k$.